# Error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase: [pytest_reports: [report files not found in build]]

Tags: dockerfile, aws-codebuild

I am building a docker image in AWS codebuild and running pytest on it.
**I've a Dockerfile which looks like this.**

```
FROM python:latest
ENV PORT=80
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /tests/
COPY . .
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install selenium
RUN pip3 install webdriver_manager
RUN apt-get install zip -y
RUN apt-get install unzip -y

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable

# Download chrome driver
RUN wget -N https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/
RUN unzip ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/
RUN rm ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN mv -f ~/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
RUN chmod 0777 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Install chrome broswer
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD ["pytest", "-v", "-s", "--junitxml=pytest_report.xml"]
```

### **The buildspec.yaml looks like this.**

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.8
    commands:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - IMAGE_TAG=build-$(echo $CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID | awk -F":" '{print $2}')
      - REPOSITORY_URI=3xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-ui-python-dkr
  build:
    on-failure: ABORT
    commands:
      - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
      - export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain
      - export PROGRESS_NO_TRUNC=1
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 359772415770.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      - docker build --progress=plain -t 3xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-ui-python-dkr .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed..
      - docker run $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
reports:
  pytest_reports:
    files:
      - ./tests/pytest_report.xml
    base-directory: ./tests
    file-format: JUNITXML
artifacts:
  files:
  - "**/*"
```

I am seeing that pytest is collecting the tests successfully and running it.

*collecting ...
collected 2 items
test_login.py::Test_login::test_01 Title==================> Google
PASSED
test_login.py::Test_login::test_02
by_locator====> ('xpath', "//input[@name='q']")
Entered Docker in search....
PASSED*
**----------------- generated xml file: /tests/pytest_report.xml -----------------**

**But the pytest_reports section failed.**

```
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Expanding base directory path: .
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Assembling file list
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Expanding .
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Expanding file paths for base directory .
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Assembling file list
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Expanding **/*
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Found 7 file(s)
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Preparing to copy TEST report pytest_reports
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Expanding base directory path:  ./tests
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Assembling file list
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Expanding ./tests
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Skipping invalid file path ./tests
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 No matching base directory path found for ./tests, skipping
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2022/07/18 20:38:27 Phase context status code:  Message: 

Error in UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS phase: [pytest_reports: [report files not found in build]]
```

I am sure this is something to do with the invalid path reference somewhere...But I am unable to figure out..
Any help is much appreciated.